# Startup scripts for IPython cluster engines

Tags: ipython, cluster-computing

I really like how you can put scripts in the profile/startup/ directory to prepare your IPython console before you use it, but it doesn't seem like ipcluster engines load these, even though they're set to use the right profile. Is there a way to load a number of scripts into an IPEngine at start? I saw the IPEngineApp.startup_script config, which I suppose I can point to a script that in turn runs the scripts in startup/, but that seems clunky.